# Using ODE Event Location and using Solution at Event as Input into ode45

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, mathematical-modeling

I have been attempting to re-create a plot found in the following paper:

http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0964-1726/4/4/006/meta

The plot I am trying to re-create is on page 267 top right hand corner, specifically, $x(t)$ vs. $t$.

The ODE used in the paper is
$$m\ddot{x}(t)+k_0x(t)+k_1(x(t)-x_s)=0$$
where $x_s$ is a piece-wise constant function defined by $x_s=x(t_r)$ whenever $\dot{x}(t_r)=0$.

The plot is generated using the values $m=1,k_0=150,$ and $k_1=50.$

The code to solve this is given as:

```
tstart = 0;
tfinal = 2;

tspan = [tstart tfinal];
u0 = [1; 0];
refine = 4;
options = odeset('Events', @resetevent , 'OutputSel' , 1, 'Refine', refine);

tout = tstart;
uout = u0';
teout = [];
ueout = [];
ieout = [];
ue = [];
while tout(end) < tfinal

% Solve until the first terminal event.
[t, u, te, ue, ie] = ode45(@(t,u) sys(t, u, ue), [tstart tfinal] , u0, options);

% Accumulate output.  This could be passed out as output arguments.

nt = length(t);
tout = [tout; t(2:nt)];
uout = [uout; u(2:nt,:)];
teout = [teout; te];          % Events at tstart are never reported.
ueout = [ueout; ue];
ieout = [ieout; ie];


% Set the new initial conditions, with .9 attenuation (??).

u0 = [u(nt,1) ; u(nt,2)];

% A good guess of a valid first timestep is the length of the last valid
% timestep, so use it for faster computation.  'refine' is 4 by default.
options = odeset(options,'InitialStep',t(nt)-t(nt-refine),...
    'MaxStep',t(nt)-t(1));

tstart = t(nt);
end

figure(1)
set(gcf,'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1])

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(tout,uout(:,1));
title(['Time history of $x(t)$'],'interpreter','latex','fontsize',20)
ylabel('$x$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',15)
xlabel('$t$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',15)
xlim(tspan)

grid on
hold on

subplot(2,1,2);
plot(tout,uout(:,2))
title('Time history of $\dot{x}(t)$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',20)
ylabel('$\dot{x}$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',15)
xlabel('$t$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',15)
xlim(tspan)

grid on
hold on

subplot(2,1,1);
stairs(teout,ueout(:,1))
title('Time history of $x_s(t)$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',20)
xlabel('$t$','interpreter','latex','fontsize',15)
xlim(tspan)

grid on
hold on

% 
function dz = sys(t, z , us)
dz = zeros(2,1);
if isempty(us) == 1
    us = 0;
else
    us;
end

% if isempty(us) == 1
%     us = 0;
% elseif us(1) == 1
%     us(1) = -1;
% else
%     us;
% end

m = 1;
k0 = 150;
k1 = 50;

dz(1) = z(2);
dz(2) = - ((k0 + k1)/m)*z(1) + (k1/m)*us(1);
end


% Reset Event Function
function [lookfor, stop, direction] = resetevent(t, z)
% Locate the time when xdot passes through zero in any direction
% and stop integration.
lookfor = z(2);  % when xdot = 0
stop = 1;        % stop the integration
direction = 0;   % any direction
end
```

The plot produced with `u0 = [1 ; 0]` is 
[image]

The plot produced with `u0 = [1 ; -eps]` is 
[image]

The plot produced with `u0 = [u(nt,1) ; 0]` as the restart initial condition is
[image]

I have a couple questions related to this:

1. What's confuses me is that for some reason Matlab does actually find
   the first zero of $\dot{x}$ and inputs into the function, but the
   documentation on [ODE Event Location](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ode-event-location.html#bu7whe8) says it skips the first
   terminal event. It's probably something I'm doing wrong, but I can't
   see what it is.
2. If you look at plot for $\dot{x}(t)$, at the points where it passes     through zero, I have the initial conditions start with the
   last value it ended with and it gives a kink in the plot, which means the derivatives don't match. I tried
   using 0 as the initial value, which makes sense to me, but it causes the solver to diverge.
   I'm not sure what the 0.9 attenuation does and I tried messing with
   that to no avail.

If you use the commented code in the function `sys` it will force the value of `us` and the plot will look like the one in the paper, but it's too specific and not what I'm trying to do, since I want to extend this idea of resetting to a different ODE.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: s this too long of a question? Can I do anything to get some assistance on how to figure out what is going on with the ODE Event Location?

Comment: What is $x_s$ when $\dot{x}$ is not zero?

Comment: Forgot to fix that, it is a piece-wise constant function. Will edit it now.

Comment: I think you mean that $x_s(t)=x(\tau(t))$ where $\tau(t)=\sup \{ u : u \leq t,\dot{x}(u)=0 \}$.

Comment: Also, what is the size of us (the third argument of sys) as you go? Is it just scalar? If so then I don't see the need to write us(1).

Comment: Finally, I think I see the problem: if you restart when the derivative is zero, your derivative will *still* be zero, so it will probably want to detect *another* event, which will cause deadlock (unless Matlab has some special trick to avoid such deadlock, like ignoring events that occur on the first step). A natural but maybe naive solution would be to perform a single very short step (without any event handling) to find an initial condition "after the event". This step could perhaps be done "by hand" or it could just be done with a more vanilla call to ode45.

Comment: To be specific, I would want to do something like running your ode45 with event handling, then compute dz(2) (with the control now switched over), and run another ode45 run for a duration of, say, 1e-9/dz(2), before starting another ode45 run with the event handling. By then, $\dot{x}$ should be appreciable and you shouldn't have any problem with deadlock. This might be slow of course, which is why it wouldn't surprise me if Matlab has some special trick...but if you're getting the wrong behavior then you might want to try the "slow but more obviously right" option.

Comment: I think you're definition of $x_s(t)$ is what I have. The way I have it is, let $t_i^r=1,2,\dots,$ be the times such that $\dot{x}=0$. Then $x_s(t)=x(t_i^r)$ where $t_i^r\leq t\leq t_{i+1}^r$. 

The event location function does in fact disregard the first terminal event, that is , the first time $\dot{x}=0$. This is what's confusing is that it does find it. I did manually remedy the situation by starting slightly below zero, namely, having `u0 = [1 ; -eps]`. I would prefer not to hard code anything, especially since it should skip the first event and would rather understand what's going on.

Comment: The third input `us` is the vector which contains the solution at the time of the event, and so, $u_s=[ u_{s_x}\,\, u_{s_{\dot{x}}}]^T.$

Comment: Yeah, I think you can avoid hardcoding things by doing something like this. Let's say I was doing $x''(t)+(2+x(\tau(t))x(t)=0$ where $\tau(t)$ is defined like in your problem. Then I would run ode45 until an event, then switch over my sys function and run ode45 for a fixed, short duration (say 1e-9/dz(2), for instance) with the event handling disabled. Then repeat that cycle. That will avoid any issues with events being found immediately after an event was already found.

Comment: Matlab probably has a more clever way to do this, but at least this will remove that from the code, which will allow you to isolate other problems if there are any.

Comment: In particular, to replicate that plot you will want to *start* with the short duration simulation to get yourself away from the extremum, and then proceed with the cycle that I described. This won't get you to exactly [1;-eps], which is good because that's a very ad hoc, error prone way to do the setup.

Comment: @Ian, Thank you for your answers. I implemented something like what you mentioned above and it fixed the issue. I'll be happy to award you the answer if you post it in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this problem by moving forward a short duration in time, for example $10^{-9}/|\ddot{x}|$, after each event, using a call to ode45 with no event handling. This will move you forward along the curve to a point where $\dot{x}$ is definitely not zero (unless your solution is somehow quite nasty). Then you can restart there with event handling re-enabled.

In particular, since the plot in the original paper has an extremum at the very start but the "control" is not supposed to kick in until the first "interior" extremum, you will want to move forward a little bit from the initial condition before enabling event handling as well.

It's not very clear to me why this is necessary; it seems like it would be routine to find an event, move forward to outside some neighborhood of the event, and then continue searching for an event.